# How To get specific data from mysql in NodeJs REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

Here is my database:

[image: db]

Here is my code

```js
//Read by jenis_kelamin
router.get('/:table/jk/:jenis_kelamin', function(req, res) {
 sequelize.query("SHOW KEYS FROM `"+TABLE_PREFIX+req.params.table+"` WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
 .then(function(keys) {
  var jenis_kelamin =req.params.jenis_kelamin;
  sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `"+TABLE_PREFIX+req.params.table+"` WHERE jenis_kelamin = `"+jenis_kelamin+"` ", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(function(rows) {
   if(!rows.length) {
    res.status(404);
    res.json({
     "success" : 0,
     "data" : "No rows found"
    });
   }
   res.status(200);
   res.json({
    "success" : 1,
    "data" : rows
   });
  })
  .catch( function(err) {
   res.status(404);
   res.send({
    "success" : 0,
    "message" : err.message
   });
  });
 })
 .catch( function(err) {
  res.status(404);
  res.send({
   "success" : 0,
   "message" : err.message
  });
 });
});
```

I want to get fields in table 'siswa' where 'jenis_kelamin' = 'starfish'. Use code above, but I am getting this error:

```js
{
    "success": 0,
    "message": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'starfish' in 'where clause'"
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try printing the complete query. I think you are passsing values without string quotes

Comment: also there is an awful lot of nesting and indenting.  While it is not (likely) the source of your sql problem,  I don't think it is all necessary.  I think you can "return"on the second sequelize statement and bring the subsequent "thens" back in line / level with the outer ones..

Comment: can you try hard coding the queries and making sure the code works in general.  Then putting the parameters in one at a time?  I think you are combining the different types of quotes in an incorrect manner " and ' are largely interchangeable in javascript ecosystem (e.g. not in JSON) however ` is a different beast.,

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm very new in nodejs, still little confuse about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS

```
//Read by jenis_kelamin
router.get('/:table/jk/:jenis_kelamin', function(req, res) {
    sequelize.query("SHOW KEYS FROM '"+TABLE_PREFIX+req.params.table+"' WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(function(keys) {
        var jenis_kelamin =req.params.jenis_kelamin;
        sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM '"+TABLE_PREFIX+req.params.table+"' WHERE jenis_kelamin = '"+jenis_kelamin+"' ", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
        .then(function(rows) {
            if(!rows.length) {
                res.status(404);
                res.json({
                    "success" : 0,
                    "data" : "No rows found"
                });
            }
            res.status(200);
            res.json({
                "success" : 1,
                "data" : rows
            });
        })
        .catch( function(err) {
            res.status(404);
            res.send({
                "success" : 0,
                "message" : err.message
            });
        });
    })
    .catch( function(err) {
        res.status(404);
        res.send({
            "success" : 0,
            "message" : err.message
        });
    });
});
```

THIS should work too

```
//Read by jenis_kelamin
router.get('/:table/jk/:jenis_kelamin', function(req, res) {
    sequelize.query("SHOW KEYS FROM '"+TABLE_PREFIX+req.params.table+"' WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(function(keys) {
        var jenis_kelamin =req.params.jenis_kelamin;
        return sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM '"+TABLE_PREFIX+req.params.table+"' WHERE jenis_kelamin = '"+jenis_kelamin+"' ", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    })
    .then(function(rows) {
        if(!rows.length) {
            res.status(404);
            res.json({
                "success" : 0,
                "data" : "No rows found"
            });
        }
        res.status(200);
        res.json({
            "success" : 1,
            "data" : rows
        });
    })
    .catch( function(err) {
        res.status(404);
        res.send({
            "success" : 0,
            "message" : err.message
        });
    });
});
```

AND Finally

```
router.get('/:table/jk/:jenis_kelamin', function(req, res) {

    const myTableName = sanitizeTableName(req.params.table) 
    const myFieldValue = santizeValue(req.params.jenis_kelamin)

    sequelize.query("SHOW KEYS FROM '"+ TABLE_PREFIX + myTableName +"' WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(function(keys) {
        var jenis_kelamin =req.params.jenis_kelamin;
        return sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM '"+TABLE_PREFIX+myTableName+"' WHERE jenis_kelamin = '"+myFieldValue+"' ", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    })
    .then(function(rows) {
        if(!rows.length) {
            res.status(404);
            res.json({
                "success" : 0,
                "data" : "No rows found"
            });
        }
        res.status(200);
        res.json({
            "success" : 1,
            "data" : rows
        });
    })
    .catch( function(err) {
        res.status(404);
        res.send({
            "success" : 0,
            "message" : err.message
        });
    });
});
```

where the sanitize functions make sure the input from the request doesn't subject you to injection attacks or any other nasty unexpected thing.

Comment: @IqbalKurniaone I am glad it worked, please accept the answer